# DISTINCT ON field is not available on MySQL. Which equivalent do you use?

Tags: mysql, django, distinct

Let's say I've got a model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I'd like, by searching the first letter of a `first_name`, to get a list of `Person`. But each one must have a different `last_name`.

For example:
searching `M...` in the list of:

```
Frank Edmond
Marc Thomas 
Matthew Ronald
Matthew Smith
Matthew Thomas
Richard Thomas
```

will give you

```
Marc Thomas
Matthew Ronald
Matthew Smith
```

In short, how to translate in MySQL:

```
Person.objects.filter(first_name__startswith='M').distinct('last_name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT <table>.last_name FROM <table> WHERE <table>.first_name LIKE 'M%'
```

Replace `<table>` with your table name.